# Google Appscript For Loop runs only once when a function is called

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I hope you are doing dandier than usual.

I am stuck on this problem for a couple days now and I don't know where I am making a mistake. Basically, I want to copy a column from one sheet(let's call it DailyOrders), make some changes and paste it into a column in another sheet in the same workbook.

Here is what it should look like:

1: DailyOrders Column M

2: Copy 2D array to a temp variable

3: Convert those array elements to string and do the processing 1 by one and keep pushing them in another 2D array

4: Push the new 2D array to Column A in the "sort" sheet.

**The Problem:**

The for loop that should traverse the original array and push those elements into the pusher function runs for correct times when I put Logger.Log statement for testing, but only once when I call the pusher function. I have no idea why that is happening.

```
function sort(){
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("DailyOrders!M2:M4").getValues();
var newvalues = [];
for(i=0;i<values.length;i++){
  pusher(values[i]);
  Logger.log(i);
}

function pusher(item) {
  item = item.toString();
  item = item.split("|| ");
   for(i=0; i<item.length; i++){
    newvalues.push([item[i]]);        
  }
//push newvalues[] to "sort!A:A"}
```

This is my first question at stack overflow, please let me know if you need any further explanation.

Sample worksheet to regenerate the problem:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1709A3kLPQ5eVCL_bQcRSc0U33hdIz9_3juouqesHYZM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the column "M" of "DailyOrders" sheet to an array.
- When the cell value has `||`, you want to split the value and put the splitted values to the array.
- You want to put the created array to the column "A" of "sort" sheet.

#### Modification points:

- The values retrieved by `getValues` is 2 dimensional array.
- In your script, `newvalues` is not used in `sort`. By this, it is not used in `pusher()`.
- When `getDisplayValues` is used instead of `getValues`, the retrieved values are the string type. The values retrieved by `getDisplayValues` is also 2 dimensional array.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function sort() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = ss.getSheetByName("DailyOrders").getRange("M2:M").getDisplayValues();
  var newvalues = [];
  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var item = values[i][0];
    var items = item.split("||");
    if (items.length > 1) {
      for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        newvalues.push([items[j].trim()]);
      }
    } else if (item) {
      newvalues.push([item]);
    }
  }
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sort");
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, newvalues.length, 1).setValues(newvalues);
}
```

#### References:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> Thanks for a quick reply, but your answer doesn't address the problem I am facing and the code modifications you suggested don't seem to work. var item = values[i][0]; returns first character of M2, 2nd character of M3, 3rd character of M4 and so on. I don't have a problem with getting the value as an array or as a string, I just want to debug why the for loop only runs once when I call a function inside it.

In your script, the variable `i` is used in 2 for loops. By this, `i` is always initialized. And also, in your situation, `i` is always less than `values.length`. By this, the loop is not finished. I think that this is the reason of your issue. If you want to modify your script, please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
 for(i=0; i<item.length; i++){
  newvalues.push([item[i]]);        
}
```

#### To:

```
for (var j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
  newvalues.push([item[j]]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply, but your answer doesn't address the problem I am facing and the code modifications you suggested don't seem to work. var item = values[i][0]; returns first character of M2, 2nd character of M3, 3rd character of M4 and so on. I don't have a problem with getting the value as an array or as a string, I just want to debug why the for loop only runs once when I call a function inside it.

Comment: @Usmantastic Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. And I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `I just want to debug why the for loop only runs once when I call a function inside it.`, in your script, the variable `i` is used in 2 for loops. By this, `i` is always initialized. And also, in your situation, `i` is always less than `values.length`. By this, the loop is not finished. I think that this is the reason of your issue. If you want to modify your script, please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

The loop inside the function `pusher` runs only once if the array `item` has only one element. Furthermore, you have to change `i` by `j` in order to avoid messing up the  indexes. Once you have applied the `pusher` function to all the elements of `DailyOrders`, you can sort the resulting array with `sort`. Below is the modified code:

### Code

```
function sort() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("DailyOrders!M1:M10").getValues();
  var newvalues = []
  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    pusher(values[i])
  }

  function pusher(item) {
    item = item.toString()
    item = item.split("|| ")
    for (j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
      newvalues.push([item[j]]);
    }
  }

  newvalues.sort()  
}
```